# Are there any advantages of using a crossover cable to directly connect modern devices?

Tags: ethernet, layer1, cable

Modern devices [no longer need](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2219416/do-you-need-a-crossover-cable.html) a crossover cable to directly connect via an ethernet cable.
But are there any advantages of using a crossover cable anyway?
For example, does a crossover cable decrease power consumption, increase transfer speed, or decrease load on the adapter or other components?

In my example I'm using a cat 6 ethernet cable to directly connect two Ubuntu server machines, and I'm executing data transfers that nearly max out the connection bandwidth.

Comment: At this point, the main purpose of crossover cables seems to be to cause frustration when you accidentally use them for something other than ethernet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*does a crossover cable decrease power consumption, increase transfer speed, or decrease load on the adapter or other components?*"

No, not at all. The speed, power consumption, latency, etc. are all the same for a straight-through vs. a crossover cable. The bandwidth is the bandwidth. For 1000Base-T (1 Gbps on UTP) it is always 1 Gbps.